# How to increase the distance between the close minimize and maximize buttons

Tags: 16.04, unity

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS with Unity 7.4.5.

My question is quite simple. I just wanted to know if there is a way of increasing the spacing between the 3 buttons, viz., close, max, min which are present on the window.

I don't want to change the order or move them to the top right hand corner of the window. Just increase the space between them...

So, if currently they are this close:

[image]

They should appear this far:

[image]

Comment: No, there's no such options, unfortunately.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy I think it's possible in GNOME using a `spacer` tag, but probably won't work in Unity.

Comment: Okay. So, Unity has no such provision... Disappointing but hey! Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XFCE, you can open xfce4-settings-manager and change panel theme in window manager (in style tab ). You will find many button layouts there.

(This should be a comment but I dont have enough credits)

Comment: Thanks, but I am using Unity and not XFCE. This may prove to be helpful for someone like me using XFCE, so your response is much appreciated!